# Reachability was not declared in this scope

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, wifi, reachability

I would like check the device WiFi connection availability while my application starts.

So I have added `SystemConfiguration.framework`.

#### Code:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>

 - (BOOL)networkCheck{

    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus)
    {
         case NotReachable:
         {
                NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
             NSLog(@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }

 return false;

}
```

#### Errors:

**Reachability** was not declared in this scope

**NetworkStatus** was not declared in this scope

**netStatus** was not declared in this scope
\
**NotReachable** was not declared in this scope

**ReachableViaWWAN** was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

(and make sure you have Reachability.m and Reachability.h in your project!)

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded Reachability and add drag them into your project, and select the targets you want to include them in.

[Reachability Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)